# Do all towns get attacked at the same time?

Tags: die2nite

I just got into a great town, only to die on day 3, out in the desert.  This is one of many problems that have arisen from the attack being at 4:30PM (I'm in CST timezone) and me having to work for a living.

**Is there any way for me to get into a town where the attack happens at a different time?**  If it was only a few hours later, I could spend my die2nite day out searching the desert and still get home in time to get back into town.

I like the game, but unless I can adjust the schedule, it's basically unplayable for me.

Comment: Maybe log in from your mobile? Die2Nite doesn't load on Opera Mini and you won't be able to move around without Flash, but the Android browser might work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, all towns get attacked at the same time. You don't need to stay out and auto-scavenge over night however. Remember, there are a number of ways to use your AP, including construction, scavenging (sans auto-scavenge), and Workshop conversions.

Since the primary appeal of the game is the social dynamic, there should be plenty of ways to enjoy it without having to auto-scavenge overnight.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it just feels like a waste to not use all those hours in the day...

Answer (score 2):

If you can't get on your computer before the attack to get inside the gates, then just dump all your AP in the Workshop or at Construction.  You can still be useful and contribute that way